# How to reference a tab name with a formula

Tags: excel, formulas

Here's the set-up in Excel.  I have several hundred tabs, each with a different name.  The first tab is a Summary tab, that references specific data fields on the subsequent pages.

e.g.
Row 7
Column A of the summary sheet has this:
='the red fox'!$a$1
Column B has:
='the red fox'!$a$7
Column C has:
='the red fox'!$a$9

What I want to do is, using a formula, determine that the first columnar reference is to 'the red fox', and use that to drive all other references for that row.

In my business Basic days it would be like:

A$='The red fox'

="'"+A$+"'"+"!$a$1"

God I hope I've made myself clear.

OK, thank you both for your help.  I think we're real close.

The following are the first three rows of the spreadsheet:

```
Column 1                    Column 2
`=’abc company’!$c$13       =’abc company’!$c$5
=Aberdeen!$c$13             =Aberdeen!$c$5
=’month of April’!$c$13     =’month of April’!$c$5
```

Column 1 will supply me with the client code from a specified cell on all worksheets. Column 2 will supply me the name of the client

Rather than typing these sheet names for each column I want to look at, I’d like to have a formula when I could pull out the tab name (in a hidden cell if need be, but better to simply use the formula in each other cell).

This way I wouldn’t have to do a replace (as I do now) for all values from the old tab name to the new tab name when I’m cloning a worksheet.

There could be 5-600 worksheets, and that's to start with!  That’s tedious.

Does this clarify things at all?

I couldn’t find a posting for taking a formula, converting it to text information, then parsing and extracting only the selected data.

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 2):

Use the Indirect() so in some cell like A1 you would put `The red fox` then you would use:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $A1 & "'!A1")
```

Now this is not "draggable" as in when it is dragged down the firs $A1 will change with the rows but the last A1 will not as it is in the Quotes.  To make that reference "draggable" use this:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $A1 & "'!" & ADDRESS(ROW(1:1):COLUMN(A:A)))
```

This starts addressing cell A1 on the sheets whose name is in $A1 and will change one column when dragged across and one row for every row dragged down.

EDIT:

In B1 put:

```
=INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,FIND("!",FORMULATEXT(A1))-1) & "C5")
```

This will find the Sheet name from the formula in A1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS`.  But since your row numbers don't seem to follow a pattern, you might want to reference them in a contiguous row of cells.  Eg. in row 6.

If your row numbers are in Row 6, and your sheet name in A1, then try:

```
A7:  =ADDRESS(A6,1,,,$A$1)
```

or, if you want the referenced value, wrap the above in `INDIRECT`

```
A7:  =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A6,1,,,$A$1))
```

eg:

[image]

Comment: Thanx Ron.  Got it. {finally}